# How to get "watched an episode of X" instead of "watched X" in actions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

> Fahim watched an episode of The Mentalist on SideReel.

That's my activity that comes up when I watch something on sidereel. Where 'watched' is the action' and 'The mentalist' the clickable object title and 'Sidereel' is the application. But there is the additional 'an episode of' (not clickable) in the action bit.

I want to acheive something on a similar effect but when I define by Action which is "watch" I get :

> Fahim watched The mentalist on sidereel

Where 'The mentalist on sidereel' is the object.title

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is "flexible sentences": Learn more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/01/03/better-open-graph-stories-with-flexible-sentences/